# How to detect when bluetooth finishes reading?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am working with Android Studio and my current task is to connect the peripheral device using Bluetooth and read data, which is sent from this remote device. Everything works OK but this data comes piece by piece and how is it possible to handle when InputStrem finishes reading?

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private BluetoothSocket mSocket;
    private InputStream mInStrem;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;

        try {
            tmpIn = mSocket.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage().toString());
        }

        mInStrem = tmpIn;
    }


    public void run() {
        mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int numBytes;

        while (true) {
            try {
                numBytes = mInStrem.read(mBuffer);
                String str = new String(mBuffer, 0, numBytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage().toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
CS:
.iv
EP: E2005175880D0242236024C9
OK:
C
.iv
ME: N
o Transponder found
ER:005
```

This is transferred data and how can I fetch only 'E2005175880D0242236024C9' this string?

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth SPP (serial port profile) is a endless stream of data (or rather two stream - one in each direction). The stream ends when the connection is closed.

If your data needs to be split into well-defined packets, you have to implement it yourself. You'll need some sort of packet divider or end-of-packet marked.

Typical marks are:

- Line break (CR, LF, or CR/LF) if you have a text protocol
- Some character or sequence of characters that does not otherwise appear in the packets
- A timeout, i.e. the start of a new packet is assumed if no further data was transmitted for 100ms

It looks as if you are dealing with a text protocol and could use line break as a delimiter. If so, the code could look like:

```
try (InputStreamReader isr= new InputStreamReader(mInStrem, StandardCharsets.ASCII);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr)) {
    String line = reader.readLine();
    // do something with line

} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Comment: I think to use Thread.sleep() to wait while data come into one string. Is it possible to lose any character?

Comment: In theory, you can certainly lose data. It's an endless stream of data with a limited buffer. But in practice, if you sleep for a fraction of a second, it should work. I don't know the details. So you'll have to test it.

Comment: I have already tested it in several times, I tried 2 seconds and it worked but I'm afraid of losing character :/

Comment: But I think 2 seconds is quite enough to scan NFC tags.